# Prefetch Images from URL

Tags: react-native

I am trying to learn a little more about React Native's ability to prefetch images from the internet. My overall goal is to basically build a slideshow, but when rerendering with a different photo.. you don't see this weird white flash

One of my issues is the Image.Prefetch documentation is pretty limited and I am having a hard time figuring out how it works

First I create this.state.picArray and create an array of 4 pictures

```
  picArray: ['https://snap-photos.s3.amazonaws.com/img-thumbs/960w/5ECBT47XF5.jpg',
                'https://snap-photos.s3.amazonaws.com/img-thumbs/960w/8N1P2AHD0W.jpg',
                'https://snap-photos.s3.amazonaws.com/img-thumbs/960w/SFJPODPJY4.jpg',
                'https://snap-photos.s3.amazonaws.com/img-thumbs/960w/5ECBT47XF5.jpg'
       ]
```

I try to conduct the prefetching for each image I have in the array I created above in the componentDidMount

```
  componentDidMount() {
   var prefetchTask = Image.prefetch('https://snap-photos.s3.amazonaws.com/img-thumbs/960w/5ECBT47XF5.jpg');
   var prefetchTask1 = Image.prefetch('https://snap-photos.s3.amazonaws.com/img-thumbs/960w/8N1P2AHD0W.jpg');
   var prefetchTask2 = Image.prefetch('https://snap-photos.s3.amazonaws.com/img-thumbs/960w/SFJPODPJY4.jpg');
   var prefetchTask4 = Image.prefetch('https://snap-photos.s3.amazonaws.com/img-thumbs/960w/5ECBT47XF5.jpg');

  }
```

and then I show the pictures like this, using another variable as like an index, and when the picture is tapped incriments and shows the next picture in the array

```
<Image  source={{ uri: this.state.picArray[this.state.id] }}
                        style={styles.deck} />
```

It might seem liek this has faster loading time but I am not sure that it does, is this the correct way to prefetch these images? My ultimate goal is to have no white flash inbetween switching pictures. Any help would be a huge thanks

Comment: `componentDidMount` would run after your `render` call, so maybe try doing this in the `constructor`. I also had issue following that documentation, so good luck getting that working.

Answer (score 0):

ComponentWillMount should be the right callback, because it is called right before the mounting. If you won't pass the prefetched images through props the constructor may also work. If you pass them and eventually change them you may call the prefetch on the wrong items as a race condition.